# What Activities Stop Computer from Sleeping

Tags: power-management, sleep

I generally set up power hungry servers with a fairly short timeout before they're supposed to suspend or hibernate, but they seem to occasionally go to sleep during file transfers, ssh sessions, etc. What sort of activities are considered "activity" of the sort that will keep the machine awake?

Comment: Are you asking about the Ubuntu server edition?

Comment: I think I eventually installed desktop on the one I'm specifically referring to. Answers specific to either would be appreciated though.

Comment: I think desktops go by desktop usage: ie, move the mouse or type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone above has posted in a comment, it seems to be mouse or keyboard activity that keeps the machine awake. I'm not marking this answer correct, as it's not really mine, and I can't guarantee it's accurate at this point.

Comment: Even if it's not your answer, if it answers your question, mark it as accepted. If maco post it as answer, you can accept his answer and delete this one.